# Is it possible to make an already initialised object literal an instance of a defined class?

Tags: javascript, node.js, object, ecmascript-6

I would like to know if it is possible to make an already initialised object literal into an instance of an already defined class.

```js
class ParentClass {
   bye () { console.log("Bye!"); }
}

class ChildClass extends ParentClass { 
   hello () { console.log("Hello!"); }
}

let obj = { foo: function (){ console.log("foo foo!"); } }

// [JS code that i wish i knew] //

obj.hello() // "Hello!" 
obj.bye() // "Bye!"
obj.foo() // "foo foo!"

console.log(obj instanceof ChildClass) // true
```

Comment: See [Object.setPrototypeOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/setPrototypeOf).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's already a method for this - `setPrototypeOf`:

```js
class ParentClass {
  bye() {
    console.log("Bye!");
  }
}

class ChildClass extends ParentClass {
  hello() {
    console.log("Hello!");
  }
}

let obj = {
  foo() {
    console.log("foo foo!");
  }
};

Object.setPrototypeOf(obj, ChildClass.prototype);

obj.hello();
obj.bye();
obj.foo();
```

Comment: What is the benefit of using ```__proto__``` over ```Object.assign``` ?

Comment: Hold on - realised there's an inbuilt method for this.

Comment: Given the related warnings on [`__proto__`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto), I wouldn't bother including that approach as part of your answer. It should not be the first part (or _any_ part for that matter) that someone sees when reading your answer.

Comment: Ok, I'll remove it @RobG.

Answer (score 1):

An "initialised object literal" is just an object, how it was created is generally not important beyond the moment it's created. Objects created as if by `Object.create` or `new Object()` (such as literals) are generally called "plain objects".

ECMAScript doesn't have classes, it has prototype inheritance and a class syntax to instantiate objects that inherit from a particular constructor's prototype.

So if you want a plain object to inherit methods from a particular object's prototype without using the constructor to make the object, you can assign the required constructor's prototype to the plain object's `[[Prototype]]` using [*Object.setPrototypeOf*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/setPrototypeOf).

However, you might be better off to construct a new instance of the "class" you want and copy the plain object's properties to it using *Object.assign*, something like:

```js
class Person {
  constructor (name, age) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
  }
}

let obj = {
  name: 'fred',
  age: '37'
};

let person = Object.assign(new Person(), obj);

console.log(person.name);
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it what you want ? The obj is declared with the `new` keyword...

```
obj = Object.assign(obj, { foo: function (){ console.log("foo foo!"); } } );
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not what i am looking for, the object is already defined as an object literal! What I'm thinking is something like "obj.__proto__ = ChildClass.prototype;" I'm just not sure if that would cover everything. (or the correct way of doing it)

Comment: @PauloSantos Update with object assign

Answer (score -1):

Tested, it will do the work, the trick is `Object.assign`:

```
class ParentClass {
   bye () { console.log("Bye!"); }
}

class ChildClass extends ParentClass { 
   hello () { console.log("Hello!"); }
}

let obj = { foo: function (){ console.log("foo foo!"); } }

// [JS code that i wish i knew] // here is how it works
obj = Object.assign(new ChildClass(), obj)

obj.hello() // "Hello!" 
obj.bye() // "Bye!"
obj.foo() // "foo foo!"

console.log(obj instanceof ChildClass) // true
```